# Storing an array in SQLite3

Tags: sqlite, go, go-gorm

I understand that SQLite can't directly store an array. I have just picked up the basics of Go and using GORM with SQLite and suprised to find that GORM/SQLite can create tables based on nested Structs, which is amazing, so I thinking there is surely a way to achieve storing an array even if from another table.

Example

```golang
type Post struct {
    Title   string `json:"title"`
    Body    string `json:"body"`
    Labels  <ARRAY> `json:"labels"`
}
```

So I would want to post the data like so

```json
{
    "title":"Some title",
    "body":"Hello world this is a post",
    "labels":["go", "programming"]
}
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this in GORM?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to populate and embedded array with gorm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994759/how-to-populate-and-embedded-array-with-gorm)